# Which utilities are available during Internet Recovery?

Tags: mac, internet-recovery

When booting up from a regular macOS recovery partition there are a couple tools available including:

- Disk Utility
- Firmware Password Utility

Are these tools also available when booting up from **internet recovery**? Does it depend on model or model year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, All the tools(Disk Utility & Firmware Password) are available when you are booting through internet recovery.While normal recovery keeps a copy of your currently running(Updated) macOS and Internet Recovery will restore to by default macOS to which version comes with your Mac.